# How to compare instances of different models with the same abstract model as their base?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have these models (non-practical code, it's just an example):

```
class BaseArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ArticleWithColor(BaseArticle):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class ArticleTypeWithSmell(BaseArticle):
    smell = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

When saving an Article (Color or Smell article), I would like to check whether there are any other existing instances that have the same values for the shared fields (those being the BaseArticle fields).

In other words: how can I check whether there already exists an ArticleWithColor with the same values for the fields it has inherited from BaseArticle as the ArticleWithSmell I'm about to save?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to protect yourself from duplicating data you can use unique_together option. Otherwise use model_to_dict(from django.forms.models import model_to_dict) to take model properties and compare them. I am not sure whether it returns pk/id as part of the dict but if so you should remove it before compare.

Comment: My main issue is that I would like to be able to check whether any model properties are derived from the abstract model and whether these properties have the same values in other models derived from the abstract model.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my answer to query all the children models. That's only one way to build the models list. It depends of your use case.

You can probably do something along those lines (still not tested):

```
class BaseArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

    _childrens = set()

    # register the model on init
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseArticle, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        BaseArticle._childrens.add(self.__class__)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for model in BaseArticle._childrens:
            query = model.objects.filter(title=self.title, author=self.author, content=self.content)
            # if this Article is already saved, exclude it from the search
            if self.pk and model is self.__class__:
                query.exclude(pk=self.pk)
            if query.count():
                # there's one or more articles with the same values
                do_something()
                break
        super(BaseArticle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: `self.objects.filter` will only filter instances of the same model, not the other models that inherit from `BaseArticle`.